# Spring Integration/SFTP Poller / Failed to Create SFTP Session /Auth Fail

Tags: sftp, spring-integration

We are trying to configure SFTP Poller with Spring Integration. Following (JSCH-0.1.45 + spring-integration-sftp-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar) used in the application.

We are getting below error. Tried so many solutions as provided in this site, but did not work it out.. Getting Below error. let us know if anyone faces same issues and come up any solutions. Thanks.

```
[2/24/15 9:15:00:725 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
[2/24/15 9:15:00:737 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log Next authentication method: publickey
[2/24/15 9:15:00:749 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
[2/24/15 9:15:00:757 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive

Jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log Disconnecting from x.xx.xxx.xx port 22

LoggingHandle E org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler `handleMessageInternal java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:158)at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory.doGetSession(CachingSessionFactory.java:98)at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory.getSession(CachingSessionFactory.java:77)at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:143)at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:144)at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.doPoll(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:89)`
            at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
            at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:144)
            at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:207)
            at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
            at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
            at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
            at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:202)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:51)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:432)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:284)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:88)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:191)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:678)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:703)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
            at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:186)
            at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:154)
            ... 22 more
    Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
            at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:464)
            at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:158)
            at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:178)


Few more error logs are updated below, Connection is getting established.. but it is getting disconnected...

[2/24/15 10:35:00:014 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log Connecting to 10.34.204.86 port 22
[2/24/15 10:35:00:054 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log Connection established
[2/24/15 10:35:00:131 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
[2/24/15 10:35:00:140 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.45
[2/24/15 10:35:00:152 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes
256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
[2/24/15 10:35:00:164 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log aes256-ctr is not available.
[2/24/15 10:35:00:172 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log aes192-ctr is not available.
[2/24/15 10:35:00:184 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log aes256-cbc is not available.
[2/24/15 10:35:00:192 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log aes192-cbc is not available.
[2/24/15 10:35:00:200 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log arcfour256 is not available.
[2/24/15 10:35:00:212 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
[2/24/15 10:35:00:395 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
[2/24/15 10:35:00:404 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
[2/24/15 10:35:00:416 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
[2/24/15 10:35:00:424 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
[2/24/15 10:35:00:454 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
[2/24/15 10:35:00:464 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
[2/24/15 10:35:00:504 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
[2/24/15 10:35:00:512 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log Host '10.34.204.86' is known and mathces the RSA h
ost key
[2/24/15 10:35:00:520 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
[2/24/15 10:35:00:532 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
[2/24/15 10:35:00:541 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
[2/24/15 10:35:00:564 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
[2/24/15 10:35:00:746 GMT+00:00] 0000002d jsch          I org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger log Disconnecting from 10.34.204.86 port
```

Comment: Did you check server-side log?

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your reply.. Yes. We are using Websphere 6.x version.  We have verified the server logs, Initially it is getting connected and got disconnected. Logs are pasted in the above. Also we have tried as per the below Jira http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/jsch-0.1.51-rc8.zip, but getting same error. Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail. let me know if you have any further info requires....

Comment: Are you sure the above is server-side log? It looks like client log to me.

Comment: He means look in the auth log on `10.34.204.86`. Also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: Hi Martin/Gary, Thanks for your prompt reply.. We were unable to trace the auth.log from the below path... on SFTP server(/Var/log/auth.log) path..  Do we have any other ways to explore to check the failed attempts in the Sever log path..